# How to adjust my seach box and search button to have the same height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code inside my view:

```
 <form class="customSearch"method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">
    <input  class="searchInput" placeholder="Search by tag.." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary"/>
 </form>
```

But the result is that I have my search box & bottom being not at the same height as follow:

[image]

Is there a way to modify my HTML to force their heights to be exactly the same.

Comment: Could you post the css code related to those elements? Or just use jsfiddle to post a testcase.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an own css style for the box which pushes the search form down or the search button up.

I don't know which twitter Bootstrap version you use but you could e.g. add a class with name "push-up-button" to your search button and define this class in css with:

```
.push-up-button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Your button should than be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary push-up-button"/>
```

Comment: could you then provide some html snipped and some css code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same properties specially the `line-height`:

```
 .searchInput, .btn-primary {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   line-height:25px;
 }
```

View this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/s6Q6h/4/**.

You need to set an equal height in both so take care with the border of the input you can take off 2px of the `line-height` in input for the border.

Comment: unfortunately this did not have any difference.

Comment: then is another off element on your css or external element can you post your css or make a fiddle?